# How do I generate Drupal Taxonomy Breadcrumbs from two vocabularies?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, taxonomy

I have discovered the magic of Taxonomy Breadcrumb ( http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_breadcrumb ). I have two dimensions in which I would like to classify my content:

Season

- Fall 2010
- Winter 2010
- Spring 2011

Type

- Letter
- Article
- Biography

I would like to set Taxonomy Breadcrumb to set up a trail like so:

Home > [season] > [type] > [node]

When viewing an individual node. I could merge all of these terms into a single, hierarchical vocabulary, but then I would need to add new parents to each of the terms that were in the Type vocabulary, each time I add a new season right? Is there an easier/better way? Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way.

I would still want people to be able to browse through content using just one of the vocabularies (all types in Spring Fall 2010 vs. all Seasons, but the content must be a letter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breadcrumbs signify hierarchy: *Node* is a member/child of *Type*, which is a member of *Season*, etc. So, unless you actually make *Type* a child of *Season*, I don't think there's any breadcrumb module that's going to do what you need to do.

Also think about it from a user experience perspective: if I'm on *Node*, I see *Type* is the next level up. If *Type* isn't a child of *Season*, the breadcrumb changes entirely when I click on *Type*. That's not expected behavior.

You're better off sorting out the IA now and making things that need to be hierarchies of each other actually hierarchies of each other.

P.S. if you like Taxonomy Breadcrumbs, you might also enjoy [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs), which can do a lot of different customizations to the breadcrumb based on token.